# Reading non-rectangular data in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a fairly large data set in csv format that I'd like to read into R. The data is annoyingly structured (my own fault) as follows:

```
,US912828LJ77,,US912810ED64,,US912828D804,...
17/08/2009,101.328125,15/08/1989,99.6171875,02/09/2014,99.7265625,...
```

And with the second line style repeated for a few thousand times. The structure is that each pair of columns represents a timeseries of differing lengths (so that the data is not rectangular).

If I use something like

```
>rawdata <- read.csv("filename.csv")
```

I get a dataframe with all the blank entries padded with NA, and the odd columns forced to a factor datatype.

What I'd like to ultimately get to is either a set of timeseries objects (for each pair of columns) named after every even entry in the first row (the "US912828LJ77" fields) or a single dataframe with row labels as dates running from the minimum of (min of each odd column) to max of (max of each odd column).

I can't imagine I'm the only mook to put together a dataset in such an unhelpful structure but I can't see any suggestions out there for how to deal with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to parse every odd column to date

```
odd.cols = names(rawdata)[seq(1,dim(rawdata)[2]-1,2)]
for(dateCol in odd.cols){
    rawdata[[dateCol]] = as.Date(rawdata[[dateCol]], "%d/%m/%Y")
}
```

Now I guess the problem is straightforward, you just need to find min, max values per column, create a vector running from min date to max date, join it with rawdata and handle missing values for you `US*` columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This has reduced the problem to something much more tractable.